# Unique id per first letter in array key?

Tags: php

I have a array that looks like this:

```
$array = array(
    "aceton" => "description here",
    "acetonurie" => "description here",
    "adipositas" => "description here",
    "bolus" => "description here",
    "cataract" => "description here",
    "cortisol" => "description here",
);
```

Next I build a definitionlist using the array data:

```
<dl>
<?php foreach ($array as $key => $value): ?>
<dt><?php echo $key; ?><dd><?php echo $value; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

That works fine offcourse but I need something more.
I need a way to generate a id per unique first letter, so the result becomes:

```
<dl>
<dt id="a">aceton <dd>description here
<dt>acetonurie <dd>description here
<dt>adipositas <dd>description here
<dt id="b">bolus <dd>description here
<dt id="c">cataract <dd>description here
<dt>cortisol <dd>description here
et cetera..
</dl>
```

Any idea how to get it done?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.  You need to close your `dt` and `dd` tags.

Comment: @danronmoon you are of course assuming an xhtml doctype has been specified because it is perfectly legal to omit closing tags for `dt` and `dd` elements in any of the [html specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
   <dl>
  <?php 
    $tmp=array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value): ?>

  <dt <?php if(!in_array($key[0],$tmp))
   { echo "id='".$key[0]."'"; array_push($tmp,$key[0]); } ?> >
  <?php echo $key; ?>
  </dt>

   <dd><?php echo $value; ?></dd>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
  </dl>
```

I got,

```
     <dl>
     <dt id="a">aceton</dt><dd>description here</dd>
     <dt>acetonurie</dt><dd>description here</dd>
     <dt>adipositas</dt><dd>description here</dd>
     <dt id="b">bolus</dt><dd>description here</dd>
     <dt id="c">cataract</dt><dd>description here</dd>
     <dt>cortisol</dt><dd>description here</dd>
    </dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of first letters using another array:

```
$letters = array();

?>
<dl>
<?php foreach ($array as $key => $value): ?>
  <?php $id = in_array($key[0], $letters) ? '' : ' id="' . $key[0] . '"'; ?>
  <dt<?php echo $id; ?>><?php echo $key; ?> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the current letter. if it changes, show the id field.

```
<dl>
<?php 
    $currentLetter = null;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
?>
    <dt<?php echo ($currentLetter == substr($value, 0, 1)) ? 'id="'.substr($value, 0, 1).'"' : ""?>><?php echo $key; ?><dd><?php echo $value; ?>
<?php 
    $currentLetter = substr($value, 0, 1);
    }
?>
</dl>
```